# SQL Trigger updating after

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a question regarding triggers and i'm not sure if this is the proper way to do this. But I have a table called 'tblWell' with id, welllonglat (geography) and welllong and welllat which are decimal value types. I'm  using lightswitch to enter data which doesn't support the geography value type. So they enter long and lat and insert. Now I need to update the welllonglat (geography) value type field after the newly record has been inserted so I thought a trigger would work. I'm not that great with triggers so wondering how I get the value of welllong and welllat if the newly inserted record and then update that record welllonglat using this function. tblWell.WellLongLat=geography::Point(tblWell.WellLat, tblWell.WellLong, 4326)

right now says parameter 1 is null.. how do I get those values.. or how else can I do this? code is below thanks

```
Alter TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON  [tblWell]
After INSERT
AS  
begin
set nocount on
DECLARE @long decimal
DECLARE @lat decimal

    update
        [tblWell]
           set tblWell.WellLongLat=geography::Point(tblWell.WellLat, tblWell.WellLong, 4326)
      FROM 
        tblWell
end

go
```

according to answer below. the following code should work but I still get a null error

```
Alter TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON  [tblWell]
After INSERT
AS  

Begin
set nocount on
UPDATE A
SET WellLongLat = geography::Point(B.WellLat, B.WellLong, 4326)
FROM [tblWell] A
INNER JOIN INSERTED B
    ON A.WellUID = B.WellUID
    where B.WellLat IS NOT NULL and B.WellLong IS NOT NULL

END

go
```

Here is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblWell](
[WellUID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[WellLocation] [varchar](500) NULL,
[WellLongLat] [geography] NULL,
[WarehouseID] [int] NULL,
[ProgrammedCost] [money] NULL,
[ProductionTypeID] [int] NULL,
[WellTypeID] [int] NULL,
[OperatorID] [int] NULL,
[WellLong] [decimal](9, 6) NULL,
[WellLat] [decimal](9, 6) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tblWell] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[WellUID] ASC
)
```

Comment: make sure to mark the accepted answer to questions you ask when one solves your problem. this keeps things moving along in the stack world and makes answerers more happy to help you again since you give them a rep boost. btw Lamak's answer is the one you should accept on this question

Comment: It's really weird that it's throwing that particular error if you are checking for values that are not null. Please post the table definition and also the values that you are inserting when it throws the error

Comment: i'm really just entering a welllocation and saving without any other values just to test

Comment: @Sirus That's strange. Anyway, updated my answer to first check that it exists at least one row that has both values `NOT NULL`

Comment: ya thanks a lot, that actually works. I think you have to check before and not have it in the where statement because it doesn't like that lol

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `INSERTED` pseudo table:

```
ALTER TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [tblWell] AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON 

UPDATE A
SET WellLongLat = geography::Point(B.WellLat, B.WellLong, 4326)
FROM [tblWell] A
INNER JOIN INSERTED B
    ON A.id = B.id

END
```

If you want to check the existence of `WellLat` and `WellLong`, you can use a `WHERE`:

```
ALTER TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [tblWell] AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN 

SET NOCOUNT ON 

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED WHERE WellLat IS NOT NULL 
                                 AND WellLong IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    UPDATE A
    SET WellLongLat = geography::Point(B.WellLat, B.WellLong, 4326)
    FROM [tblWell] A
    INNER JOIN INSERTED B
        ON A.id = B.id
    WHERE B.WellLat IS NOT NULL AND B.WellLong IS NOT NULL
END

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Lamak's answer is good. here's why yours does not work. You are trying to set values from tbWell. so what your query is doing is going through every row and setting WellLongLat according to that row's WellLat and WellLong values. I imagine you have a null value for WellLat or WellLong somewhere thus the null error.

Doing as Lamak demonstrates you get the values of the just inserted row out of the INSERTED table and then match them to the row just inserted based on the id column (which should be unique). thus you end up updating one row (if id is unique) and only row and using the new values. now technically I suppose you don't HAVE to use inserted in the Set part of the update, but its better form to do so.

small note: your declares do nothing in the trigger because you never use them so no point to them

Comment: Ok thanks, ya I forgot to delete those out. Also how do I make it so it checks if exists (select a.welllat, a.welllong ) before it tries to do the update...?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. @Sirus, I Updated my answer to check for existence of a value on those columns

Comment: couple ways [column] IS NULL or COALESCE([column], [defaultvalue])...and Lamak has already addressed your point, now accept his answer ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot... unfortunately it still gives me an error data row 9 not committed, geography::point failed because parameter 1 is not allowed to be null..... the fields allow nulls.

Comment: but point function probably does not allow it. use Lamak's existence check example and your problem should be solved

Comment: @Sirus That's weird, are you sure that you are using the `WHERE` that I added on my answer?

Comment: @Sirus on each answer, under the up/down arrows there should be an outlined check. click this to accept an answer. it means you chose that as the answer to your problem. so when people look at your question later they can know it worked for you.

Comment: I updated my original post with code and yes I added the where.. doesn't work